# Aggregation using vector

Tags: c++, vector, composition, aggregation

I'd like to create an aggregation and store the objects with vector, is it correct which I wrote? :

```
 Class A
{
  private:
           vector <B *> pB;
  public:
           A();
           A(int tag);
           ~A();
  }

  A::A(int tag){
     for (i=0; i != tag, i++)
     pB.push_back(new B());
  }
```

And to create not an aggregation but a composition I only have to add this in the destructor:

```
A::~A(){
       vector <B *>::iterator citer = pB.begin();
        while (citer != pB.end())
        delete *(citer++);
        pB.clear();
 }
```

is it right?
Thank you

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector<B>`?

Comment: What else are you doing with pB (I suspect that no usage will make this the correct way but I think we need to know more to suggest the best way)

Comment: You might want to look into either `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` or `boost` `ptr_containers` instead of storing raw pointers in a container which doesn't manage them.

Comment: @KennyTM: to separate the life of A from that of B

Comment: @Mark: B is an has-a relationship with A, so I create an aggregation. pB contains a pointer to an objects that contain large sparse matrices. Class A manages these matrices.

Comment: @Grizzly: I'm a newbie, I prefer to proceed step by step

Comment: `vector` clears up itself once it goes out of scope, so not to call `clear` in the holder destructor.

Comment: @Ale: All the more reason not to do manual memory management. Afterall it's easy to make mistakes. (Btw: doing it the way you posted you need to always delete all elements in the `vector` in your destructor and also need to write your own `copy constructor` and `assignment operator` per the rule of three to create a class which is not inherently broken

Comment: @Grizzly: you know, basic books begin from raw pointers and so I have to use them to learn how they works. After that I'll change my code again to consider smart pointers. (for now, no copies of A are possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing a method to access your pointers, something like

```
B* getPtr(int iP) {
    if(iP<pB.size()) {
        return pB.at(iP);
    }
    return NULL
}
```

and to delete a single pointer of the list:

```
void delPtr(int iP) {
    if(iP<pB.size()) {
       delete pB.at(iP);
       pB.erase(pB.begin()+iP);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. In this manner I should manage the life of pB from an external class C to avoid the memory leak. If so, I guess the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

I think in your *aggregation* case you should have a method to add object to vector and not to do it in constructor.

Then a user of `A` class have to manage objects lifetime correctly.

Now your code for *aggregation* case is incorrect. You have obvious memory leak.

Comment: The number of objects are fixed when the user builds A(int tag), tag is the number of objects. But I understand my mistake.

Comment: Well, in _my understanding_ aggregating is when your object contains some other but can live without them, and composition is when it cannot. Simply if you create objects in constructor and have no possibility to remove them latter, your `A` cannot live without objects.

Comment: yes, I think you are right and now I have a memory leak in the case of aggregation. Adding a function getpB() to get the addresses of the objects of B should be the right solution, thank you